# Plotting data on a Flot Chart using angularjs and json using $http

Tags: php, mysql, json, angularjs, flot

I created an application using angularjs, php and mysql. I have set an RESTful API which exports the mysql data to json. I would like to know how to plot the "Copra_Mc" data alone on a flot line chart using the below JSON data.

```
  [
    {
    "productionhourlyNumber": "94",
    "Copra_Mc": "5.88741898",
    "Copra_Oil": "0.64851388"
    },
    {
    "productionhourlyNumber": "93",
    "Copra_Mc": "6.88741898",
    "Copra_Oil": ""
    },
    {
    "productionhourlyNumber": "92",
    "Copra_Mc": "5.89998",
    "Copra_Oil": ""
    }
]
```

HTML

```
<div class="tile-body" ng-controller="LineChartCtrl">
  <flot dataset="dataset" options="options" height="250px"></flot>
</div>
```

JS

I have set dummy json in the controller, i would like fetch data from the above json using $http instead of the dummy data

```
    .controller('LineChartCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.dataset = [{
      data: [[1,20.3],[2,5.9],[3,7.2],[4,8],[5,7],[6,6.5],[7,6.2],[8,6.7],[9,7.2],[10,7],[11,6.8],[12,7]],
      label: 'Copra_Mc',
      points: {
        show: true,
        radius: 6
      }
    }, {
      data: [[1,6.6],[2,7.4],[3,8.6],[4,9.4],[5,8.3],[6,7.9],[7,7.2],[8,7.7],[9,8.9],[10,8.4],[11,8],[12,8.3]],
      label: 'OEE',
      points: {
        show: true,
        radius: 6
      }
    }, {
      data: [[1,9.6],[2,7.4],[3,8.6],[4,13.4],[5,8.3],[6,7.9],[7,14.2],[8,7.7],[9,8.9],[10,8.4],[11,8],[12,8.3]],
      label: 'OVE',
      points: {
        show: true,
        radius: 6
      }
    }];
      }
    };
   })
```

The chart looks like this
[image: Flot chart of above data]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use flow chart directive to use json by $http

download directive for flot chart in angularjs here

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-flot
https://github.com/ErikAugust/angularjs-flot-chart-directive
```

and  use similar to this

```
http://www.codeandyou.com/2015/02/injecting-service-to-directives-in.html
```

Comment: I am using directive for flot chart in angularjs, i am having a hard time isolating "Copra_Mc" alone from the above json to plot on graph